# How to achieve Gmail-like appearance using Material 3 NavigationBar in Flutter with no text label and no space for label text?

Tags: flutter

I'm using `Material 3` **NavigationBar**, and aiming for a **Gmail**-like appearance with no text label and no space for label text in the navigation bar at bottom.

### Source code:

```dart
          bottomNavigationBar: NavigationBar(
            backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFF2F6F3),
            indicatorColor: const Color(0xFFB9F0CB),
            selectedIndex: _currentIndex,
            onDestinationSelected: (int index) {
              setState(() {
                _currentIndex = index;
              });
            },
            // selectedLabelStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 0),
            // unselectedLabelStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 0),
            destinations: const <NavigationDestination>[
              NavigationDestination(
                selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.window),
                icon: Icon(Icons.window_outlined),
                label: '',
              ),
              NavigationDestination(
                selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                icon: Icon(Icons.search_outlined),
                label: '',
              ),
              NavigationDestination(
                selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.person),
                icon: Icon(Icons.person_outline),
                label: '',
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

### Actual output with space for label still there:

[image: Received output]

### Expected output with no space for label:

[image: Expected output]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a simple solution, just add below code inside **NavigationBar**:

```dart
  labelBehavior: NavigationDestinationLabelBehavior.alwaysHide,
```

### Reference:

This playground below by Flutter demonstrates difference between available `labelBehavior` options.

[Flutter NavigationBar class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/NavigationBar-class.html#material.NavigationBar.2)

### Final code:

```dart
          bottomNavigationBar: NavigationBar(
            backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFF2F6F3),
            indicatorColor: const Color(0xFFB9F0CB),
            selectedIndex: _currentIndex,
            onDestinationSelected: (int index) {
              setState(() {
                _currentIndex = index;
              });
            },
            labelBehavior: NavigationDestinationLabelBehavior.alwaysHide,
            // selectedLabelStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 0),
            // unselectedLabelStyle: const TextStyle(fontSize: 0),
            destinations: const <NavigationDestination>[
              NavigationDestination(
                selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.window),
                icon: Icon(Icons.window_outlined),
                label: 'Home',
              ),
              NavigationDestination(
                selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.search),
                icon: Icon(Icons.search_outlined),
                label: '',
              ),
              NavigationDestination(
                selectedIcon: Icon(Icons.person),
                icon: Icon(Icons.person_outline),
                label: '',
              ),
            ],
          ),
```

[image: Final Output]